# Trigger an action when the number of success messages gets a certain number using Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

We have an operation that have to be triggered when a certain number of messages have been sent in a Spring Integration pipeline.

In fact when the sum of Discarded Messages plus Successfully sent messages plus Error sent messages ( in a HttpComponentsMessageSender ) arrive to a certain number.

I've seen there is something called "" that stores the metrics, but how to trigger something based on its numbers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an `Aggregator` EI pattern is fully for you:

http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Aggregator.html
http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator

So, you correlate all those messages with some `correlationStrategy`.
The custom `releaseStrategy` decides if a condition for all messages in that group has been met and you produce a message from that aggregator to some channel for performing a desired trigger action.

Comment: The thing @artem-bilan is that I can use headers.sequenceSize on the aggregator but the value that gives me the correct number of elements comes from another element ( a database query message having only one field TOTAL_ELEMENTS )..... so, how I do the comparison in the release strategy ?

Comment: You can store that `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` in the message headers and consult it from the `releaseStrategy`. If it reflects the number of messages in group, of course. Otherwise you should ask yourself: "what makes my group to be ready for release?"

Comment: but, the thing is I have one line that goes to the aggregator, and gets messages from a queue ( several thousand ) and then I have nother line that gest a single message with the total number of elements that I should treat. How I can use this second line in the first line aggregator release strategy ?

Comment: ??? Please, read about an aggregator. Looks like you treat `releaseStrategy` not correctly. As for me you have only two messages for aggregator - first and second line, in your terms. Please, start a new SO thread with the proper description of the task. Otherise your concerns are not clear.